# Bash команда с префиксом sudo пропадает

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sudo

Ubuntu 14.04, смотрим есть ли у нас программка:

```
which passenger-config
usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/passenger-config
```

Есть!

Спрашиваем с sudo

```
~# sudo which passenger-config
~#
```

Нету!
Как это поправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urmurmur, когда `which` ищет программы, он ищет исполняемые файлы с идентичным названием в текущем `$PATH`. Таким образом, например, ничего из `/usr/sbin/` не попадет к обычному пользователю, пока кто-то не начал химичить  переменными.
Очевидно, у текущего пользователя `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/` записан в `$PATH`, но при выполнении через sudo используется другой `$PATH` (я честно не знаю, от рута ли в этом случае выполняются команды, скорее всего да).

Comment: Можете пожалуйста в ответ добавить способ как добавить в судошный PATH нужную директорию?

Comment: @urmurmur, лучше указывать полный путь (я абсолютно серьезно сейчас). Вам в любом случае так или иначе придется его указывать. Вы, безусловно можете отредактировать `/etc/environment` или аналог, но я бы **очень** не рекомендовал вам играться с системой таким способом, я сам как-то убил таким образом виртуалку. Альтернативное решение - сделать symlink на необходимый файл в `/usr/local/bin`: `ln -s /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/bin/passenger-config /usr/local/bin/passenger-config`.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Еще вариант как в итоге я это вылечил - использовать опцию `sudo -i`. Это симулирует авторизацию и использует нужный environment.

Answer (score 0):

**env** и **sudo env** пробовали сравнить?
Сначала надо сравнить вывод этих команд в части переменной окружения PATH, наверняка во втором случае отсутствует путь к вашему файлу passenger-config. Добавьте этот путь хотя бы в /etc/profile.

Comment: они очень разные. браво?)

Comment: вы можете пожалуйста отредактировать свой ответ и там написать что именно нужно сделать?